# How do I get the posts in a topic in Django?

Tags: python, django

Okay I'm trying to get the posts in a topic in Django, but not sure how. I have tried many methods.

**forums/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Attachment(models.Model):
        file = models.FileField()
        def __str__(self):
                return self.file
class Category(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.title
class Topic(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        description = models.TextField()
        category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.title
class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        body = models.TextField()
        topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.title

class Reply(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        body = models.TextField()
        post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.title
```

Thanks in advance, if you need any other details let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Call `FOO_set` (where FOO is the source model name - in your case post) on Topic instance.

```
topic = Topic.objects.get(id=1)
topic.post_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=1)
posts = Posts.objects.filter(topic=topic)
```

Return all posts from topic with id=1